# How to evaluate these integrals in hydraulic?

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

I am studying about hydraulics, there are integrals that I don't know how to evaluate. Here is the problem:

> Equation of velocity is:  $$U_r=K(R^2-r^2)$$ Where $U_r$ is velocity
> at radius $r$ and $R$ is radius of the pipe and $K$ is constant. Find
> energy and momentum coefficients ($\alpha$ and $\beta$).

We have:  $\alpha=\cfrac{\int v^3dA}{V^3.A}$ and $\beta=\cfrac{\int v^2.dA}{V^2A}$ (where $v$ is velocity and $V$ is average velocity).

I draw this:
[image]

In this figure $(R^2-r^2)$ lies on the shaded area. so $A=\pi(R^2-r^2)$. but I don't know how to calculate these integrals to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$

EDIT:

For $\alpha$ I tried it:

$V=\frac{Q}{A}$ where $Q$ is flow rate:

$$\alpha=\cfrac{\int v^3dA}{V^3.A}=\cfrac{\int v^3dA}{\dfrac{Q^3}{A^2}}=\frac{A^2}{Q^3}\int v^3 dA=\frac{A^2}{Q^3}\int(K(R^2-r^2))^3dA=\cfrac{K^3 (\pi R^2)^2}{Q^3}\times\int (R^2-r^2)^3dA $$ Using polar system: $dA=rdrd\theta$ But I am not sure what can I write for $(R^2-r^2)^3$ and what is the integral bound? I don't know how to change it to polar system integral.

Comment: Try and set up your integral and we can help if you get stuck. Just take equation of velocity and $dA = r dr d\theta$

Comment: @MathLover ok. let me try that .

Comment: @MathLover See my edit, I wrote the integral. but unfortunately I am not very familiar with polar system integral. I remember I used it for integral of $f(x,y)$ and replaced $x^2+y^2$ with $r^2$ so I don't know how to use that here.

Comment: I also doubt that this step is right $\cfrac{\int v^3dA}{\dfrac{Q^3}{A^2}}=\frac{1}{Q^3}\int A^2 v^3 d$ because I just plugged in $A^2$ into the integral. I am not sure.

Comment: OK but why did you take the $A$ from denominator inside the integral? That is the area you already know and you are multiplying that by the avg velocity, correct?

Comment: @MathLover Yes, I fixed it.

Comment: As the given velocity is not a function of angle, we can also just use $2\pi r dr$ instead of double integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle \int v^3dA = 2\pi K^3  \int_r^{R} (R^2-\rho^2)^3 \rho \, d\rho$

$\rho(R^2 - \rho^2)^3 = R^6 \rho - \rho^7 - 3\rho^3R^4 + 3 \rho^5R^2$

So your integral becomes

$ \displaystyle 2\pi K^3  \int_r^{R} (R^6 \rho - \rho^7 - 3\rho^3R^4 + 3 \rho^5R^2) d\rho$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you very much. But I don't understand why you multiplied  $2\pi K$ to integral in first equation. and we multiply it in final integral also? (it is obvious we do but I want to make sure :) )

Comment: I missed copying $2\pi K$. I am assuming $K$ is part of velocity function and also $2\pi$ comes because we are using $dA = 2\pi \, r\,  dr$ instead of doing a double integral with $r dr d\theta$. It is the same thing in this case.

Comment: Btw I see you are using $R$ as radius in the denominator. Given it is annular flow, should you not be using $(R-r)$ as the radius? Pls check on that.

Comment: I think average velocity in pipe is  flow rate divided by area of cross section of pipe. therfore I used area of circle.

Comment: But I think I shouldn't denote this area with $A$ because I defined $A=\pi (R^2-r^2)$ therfore  It is better to write $V=\frac{Q}{\pi R^2}$ instead.

Comment: Yes I read it now. It is pipe of radius R. It is not annulus. You are right in that case.

Comment: I notice that It should be $2\pi K3^3$ instead of $2\pi K$ please fix it.

Comment: Yes agree. Fixed it!